# Rendering updated components from backing bean after Save

Tags: ajax, dynamic, jsf-2, renderpartial

I have been working on creating a dynamic table that captures all cells that have been updated (for a quicker save) and then to refresh/rerender those cells after a save.

So far, I have the table being created, all of the items that are updated are being captured very nicely via ajax listener, but am now stuck on not being able to refresh/rerender those updated components after a save.

Code snippet from the page:

```
<h:form id="formMain" prependId="false">
  <div id="contentWrapper">
    <p:messages id="messages" severity="warn, error" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
    <div style="float:right; position:relative; top: -3px;">
      <h:commandButton id="btnSaveUpdates" styleClass="save_updates_button">
        <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{remediationDetail.processUpdates}"/>
      </h:commandButton>
     </div>
   <h:panelGroup id="detailEdit" styleClass="clear_left" layout="block">
     <h:dataTable id="tblDetails" styleClass="slate_table remediation" value="#{remediationDetail.details}" var="dataItem">
                    <c:forEach items="#{remediationDetail.detailHeaders}" var="key" varStatus="looper">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">#{key.fieldDefinition.fieldConfiguration.customLabel}</f:facet>
                      <c:if test="#{key.fieldDefinition.dataType.name eq 'Number'}">
                        <h:panelGroup id="detailNumberPanel#{looper.index}">
                            <h:inputText id="txtDetailNumber#{looper.index}" rendered="#{remediationDetail.containsErrors(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].val}" styleClass="remediation_textbox error_marker" title="#{remediationDetail.errorMessages(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}">
                                            <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="0" maxIntegerDigits="19"/>
                                            <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="@none" listener="#{remediationDetail.markChangedEntity}"/>
                                            <f:attribute name="entity" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index]}"/>
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <h:outputText id="txtDetailNumberOut#{looper.index}" rendered="#{not remediationDetail.containsErrors(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].val}"></h:outputText>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                              </c:if>
                      <c:if test="#{key.fieldDefinition.dataType.name eq 'Decimal'}">
                        <h:panelGroup id="detailDecimalPanel#{looper.index}">
                            <h:inputText id="txtDetailDecimal#{looper.index}" rendered="#{remediationDetail.containsErrors(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" converterMessage="Value provided is not a valid Decimal" styleClass="remediation_textbox error_marker" title="#{remediationDetail.errorMessages(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].val}">
                                            <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" maxIntegerDigits="19"/>
                                            <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="@none" listener="#{remediationDetail.markChangedEntity}"/>
                                            <f:attribute name="entity" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index]}"/>
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <h:outputText id="txtDetailDecimalOut#{looper.index}" rendered="#{not remediationDetail.containsErrors(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].val}">
                                            <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" maxIntegerDigits="19"/>
                                        </h:outputText>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                            </c:if>
                      <c:if test="#{key.fieldDefinition.dataType.name eq 'Date'}">
                        <h:panelGroup id="detailDatePanel#{looper.index}">
                                        <h:inputText id="txtDetailDate#{looper.index}" rendered="#{remediationDetail.containsErrors(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" styleClass="remediation_textbox error_marker dates" title="#{remediationDetail.errorMessages(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].val}">
                                            <f:convertDateTime locale="en_US" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                                            <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="@none" listener="#{remediationDetail.markChangedEntity}"/>
                                            <f:attribute name="entity" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index]}"/>
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <h:outputText id="txtDetailDateOut#{looper.index}" rendered="#{not remediationDetail.containsErrors(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].val}">
                                            <f:convertDateTime locale="en_US" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                                        </h:outputText>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                      </c:if>
                      <c:if test="#{key.fieldDefinition.dataType.name eq 'Boolean'}">
                        <h:panelGroup id="detailBooleanPanel#{looper.index}">
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="cbDetailBooleanInput#{looper.index}" rendered="#{remediationDetail.containsErrors(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" title="#{remediationDetail.errorMessages(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].val}">
                                <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="@none" listener="#{remediationDetail.markChangedEntity}"/>
                                            <f:attribute name="entity" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index]}"/>
                                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            <h:outputText id="txtDetailBooleanOutput#{looper.index}" rendered="#{not remediationDetail.containsErrors(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].val}"></h:outputText>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                            </c:if>
                      <c:if test="#{key.fieldDefinition.dataType.name eq 'String'}">
                        <h:panelGroup id="detailStringPanel#{looper.index}">
                                <h:inputText id="txtDetailString#{looper.index}" rendered="#{key.fieldDefinition.inputType eq 'TEXTBOX' and remediationDetail.containsErrors(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].val}" styleClass="remediation_textbox error_marker" title="#{remediationDetail.errorMessages(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}">
                                            <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="@none" listener="#{remediationDetail.markChangedEntity}"/>
                                            <f:attribute name="entity" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index]}"/>
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <h:selectOneMenu id="ddDetailString#{looper.index}" styleClass="remediation_select error_marker" rendered="#{key.fieldDefinition.inputType eq 'DROPDOWN' and remediationDetail.containsErrors(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].val}" title="#{remediationDetail.errorMessages(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}">
                                             <f:selectItems value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].fieldDefinition.listItemSet.selectItemsList}"></f:selectItems>
                                             <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="@none" listener="#{remediationDetail.markChangedEntity}"/>
                                             <f:attribute name="entity" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index]}"/>
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                        <h:outputText id="txtDetailStringOut#{looper.index}" rendered="#{not remediationDetail.containsErrors(dataItem.id, key.fieldDefinition.id)}" value="#{dataItem.entityList[looper.index].val}"></h:outputText>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                      </c:if>
                    </h:column> 
                    </c:forEach>
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

Code from the backing bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class RemediationDetail implements Serializable {
public void markChangedEntity(AjaxBehaviorEvent ajaxEvent){
    Entity entity = (Entity) Utility.getAjaxActionAttribute(ajaxEvent, "entity");
    //Capture the Client Ids that were updated
    getComponentsIdsToRefresh().add(ajaxEvent.getComponent().getParent().getClientId());
    //Capture what Entities were changed    
    getChangedEntities().add(entity);
}

 //This is where the save happens and hoping for updating of components !!
 public void processUpdates(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    entityDomain.processEntities(changedEntities);

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().addAll(getComponentsIdsToRefresh());
}

}
```

After the save occurs and I add the Client Ids to be updated to the PartialViewContext().getRenderIds() I don't see anything being updated.  I have also tried the OmniFaces Ajax.Update(clientId) with no success either.

I have updated the code snippets as it currently stands with the full table that is being built.

My Questions are:

1. Is what I am doing possible ?
2. Am I approaching the rendering of the components correctly ?
3. What am I missing ?

My Environment:
  Mojarra 2.1.7
  Tomcat 7.022

Regards,

Mike

Comment: You're positive the componentIds you're specifying for update are valid? What does your Javascript console say?

Comment: @kolossus Yes!  I definitely reviewed what was being passed to the backing bean and what was available on the page.  Even further I changed the value by prepending "formMain:" to the ID and even ":formMain:" as it would have been used in the render portion of the f:ajax tag, buy nothing has worked so far.

Comment: @MikeR What is a scope of your managed bean?

Comment: @partlov The bean is SessionScoped

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Please provide an SSCCE and mention exact JSF impl/version and container impl/version. Please also provide raw copy of ajax request and response.

Comment: @BalusC  I have updated my original example to include more code, but still trying to keep it as short as possible.

Comment: Please upgrade to Mojarra 2.1.21 (just the current version) and retry.

Comment: @BalusC I did the upgrade to 2.1.21, but still have the same result.

Comment: @BalusC The upgrade ended up doing the trick after I changed the logic of the id I was capturing back to the original code.  My post has been updated to reflect the correct method of capturing the id.

Comment: I reposted the comment as an answer.

Comment: Wait, since when is the bean view scoped? You told in a comment that it was session scoped. That would then totally explain the problem. View scoped get reconstructed on every postback when bound to a taghandler.

Comment: @BalusC  late night code posting doesn't bode well for me.  The tag handlers are working with another bean that is SessionScoped.  The rest of the page is being handled by the ViewScoped bean.  My apologies to all for the bad code example.  I have updated the example for to use SessionScoped for clarity and completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine for me on Mojarra 2.1.21. Mojarra 2.1.7 is from March 2012 and currently thus already a little over 1 year old. I strongly recommend to upgrade it.

I can't pinpoint exactly which version between 2.1.7 and 2.1.21 and/or which [Mojarra issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES) fixes your concrete problem with 2.1.7 as I don't recognize this problem, but I can tell that a lot of things have been improved in the view state management lately. Even more, since 2.1.18, the [eternal chicken-egg problem with taglibs+viewscope](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers) has been fixed, it may as well be releated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed something in your `markChangedEntity` method. You have the following code:

```
getComponentsIdsToRefresh().add("formMain:" + 
    ajaxEvent.getComponent().getParent().getClientId());
```

Calling `getClientId()` already returns the complete ID including the id of the form. Adding `formMain:` will lead to something like `formMain:formMain:XXX`, which won't be a legal ID in your view.

Comment: This is just strange. The original question's code before the editing didn't have that mistake. I'm not sure if this is just carelessness of the OP while formulating/editing the question.

Comment: @Michi The ":formMain:" wasn't there on my original post and was added by me in my different attempts at getting this resolved.  Here is the sticky point now..I changed how I was capturing the IDs and it now works, but it only worked when I combined it with BalusC's recommendation of upgrading the JSF version to the 2.1.21.  How should this be handled ?

Comment: @Michi Also, as a quick comment.  Inspecting the getClientId() I didn't see the form within the value that was returned. It returned only up as far as the table tag.

Comment: You should definitly go with the current version of Mojarra as BalusC suggested (or even better Apache MyFaces). It's probably a bug in the Mojarra version you use.